# Read all tables from one hive then write to another hive on another cluster using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

We can read or write tables from hive by putting `hive-site.xml` to the direction "conf" of spark.But now I have two cluster which can be connected to each other.Let`s say hive 1 on cluster,and hive 2 on another cluster

Now I need to read data from hive 1 and do some transformation then write to hive 2,the problem is I can only put one `hive-site.xml` file to spark conf,means when I execute

```
someDataFrame.write.saveAsTable("dbName.tableName")
```

,it will be save to hive 1 not hive 2,because spark only recognize one hive (hive 1)

My question is can I read and write to different hives on different cluster using spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there would only be one Hive Context active during this operation, I'm going to say it's not possible.

At a minimum, you would have to actually register the table in the "local" Hive metastore as an external table with `LOCATION hdfs://othernamenode:9000/table/path`, then make Spark write to it that way, but I've not tried it

Alternatively, look into the [Circus Train](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/circus-train) project for migrating Hive tables